# Print new line character as string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, string, newline

I'm working on a project which deals with strings a lot. I need to show what kind of delimiter is used in strings. I get that value from an API call. How do I print the delimiter to the console?

```
delimiter = '\n';
```

I want to print this on screen.

```
console.log(delimiter);
// prints "
          "
```

I need it to print `\n` instead of literally printing newline.

Comment: `delimiter = '\\n';`, perhaps?

Comment: It is set from API call,Which I have no access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `\n` is an escape sequence used for new lines.

That is why you need to use replace on the string if you want to see it in the console. Like so:

```js
console.log(delimiter.replace('\n', '\\n'));
```

The extra backslash escapes the `\n` so it is not longer treated as a newline.

More about escape sequences can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences

Comment: Code only answers are consider poor quality, please explain WHY you need the additional back slash.

Comment: See update.....

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.stringify()` you can transform an actual new line character (whatever it might be) into its stringified version. Then after stripping leading and trailing double quotes, you'll get what you're after:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(delimiter).replaceAll('"',''));
```

**Update:**

> How to handle double quotes and control characters inside strings that
> are delimited with newlines?

This should do the trick:

```
const delimiter = '\n';
const delimitedText = 'a\nb\nc\nd';
const stringifiedDelimiter = JSON.stringify(delimiter).replaceAll('"','');
console.log(delimitedText.replaceAll(delimiter, stringifiedDelimiter));
```

Comment: How to handle double quotes inside strings that contain double quote marks and/or control characters other than newlines?

Comment: Please see an update.

Answer (score 1):

To display a (multi)line with already wrapped text, use this

There is a little regex thing, which removes `\r` and `\n`

```js
const server = 'a\na';

const client = server.replace(/\r?\n/gm, '\\n');

console.log(1, server);
console.log(2, client);
```